# Mysql query performance issues while using several REGEXP?

Tags: mysql, regex, performance

In my query I need to have several regular expression in order to filter the user name or email because I am not interesting on them. So, I have written this query in mysql and after running it , it took so many time to give back me result. I got problem wit performance. Moreover after running this query, even don't filtering my information in the correct way. I am not sure how can I improve my query in order to :

- speed up the query response time
- applying correct filtering for
  regular expression

I will be appreciated for any help.

```
select DISTINCT t.user, vg_product_id,t.`platform`, pd.`mail`,
substring_index(group_concat(p.ts ORDER BY p.ts DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) as sub_start_ts, 
substring_index(group_concat(t.`expires_at`ORDER BY t.`expires_at` DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) as expired_time 
from users u
inner join tariff_subs_info t on (t.`user` = u.`user_xmpp_login` 
                                  and t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('^([A-Za-z]{2,3}(produsero|usero)+[0-9]{1,3})$' or '(\w+|\d+)?test(\w+|\d+)?' )
                                  and t.vg_product_id REGEXP "^(europe?|usa?|unlimited?|basic?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\_)+(and?|ios?)+$" )
left  join plus_data pd on (u.`user_xmpp_login` = pd.`user`)
inner join purchase_log p on (p.purchase_id = t.purchase_id)
WHERE (pd.mail not like '%guerrillamail.com' 
       or pd.mail is null) 
group by 1,2 ORDER BY DATE(p.ts);
```

and this is my result:

```
noadstestuser   basic_XXX_ios   ios NULL    2015-10-26 14:00:32 2015-10-26 14:05:24
brusero2    unlimited_XX_ios    ios brusero2@yhx.yg 2015-11-03 15:41:57 2015-11-03 15:46:45
brusero3    bXX_uscios  ios brusero3@tb.fff 2015-11-03 15:43:53 2015-11-03 15:48:42
esusero1    unliXX_usc  ios esusero1@es.userr   2015-11-03 13:51:54 2015-11-03 13:56:41
esusero3    basic_X_i os    esusero3@yn.yyf 2015-11-03 13:55:08 2015-11-03 14:00:02
esusero4    basic_X ios esusero4@yn.ttx 2015-11-03 14:01:50 2015-11-03 14:06:38
esusero5    unXXXed_us  ios esusero5@uh.hhb 2015-11-03 14:45:38 2015-11-03 14:50:24
esusero6    basic_XX    ios esusero6@yh.hvv 2015-11-03 14:51:22 2015-11-03 14:56:09
esusero7    unlimXX_    ios esusero7@yh.yyh 2015-11-03 15:20:35 2015-11-03 15:25:24
esusero8    basXX_usc   ios esusero8@ij.iih 2015-11-03 15:22:29 2015-11-03 15:27:14
flusero2    unlXXXe ios flusero2@yh.yog 2015-11-03 16:57:58 2015-11-03 17:02:45
nlprodusero1    baXicXX_X   ios nlprodusero1@yh.rof 2015-11-03 14:06:52 2015-11-03 14:11:44
nlprodusero2    unliXXXeds  ios nlprodusero2@uoh.df 2015-11-03 14:08:28 2015-11-03 14:13:16
prodpurchasetest    baXXc_usXc  ios NULL    2015-11-03 09:20:51 2015-11-03 09:25:41
ukusero1    basicXXsca  ios ukusero1@uj.uoh 2015-11-03 15:45:59 2015-11-03 15:48:42
ukusero2    baXXsca ios gbuser@yb.jov   2015-11-03 17:00:14 2015-11-03 17:05:07
ukusero4    unlXXd_usc  ios ukusero4@uoh.jv 2015-11-03 17:02:10 2015-11-03 17:02:45
usprodusero1    uXXited_us  ios usprodusero1@ook.ok 2015-11-03 13:30:25 2015-11-03 13:35:14
usprodusero2    bXXXs   ios usprodusero2@ok.iob 2015-11-03 13:33:39 2015-11-03 13:38:31
usprodusero5    unlXXsc ios usprodusero5@rou.tf 2015-11-03 15:34:35 2015-11-03 15:39:26
```

This result are unexpected from me and I don't want to have them. Despite of using `NOT REGEXP`, all these lines came as my results. How can I solve these situation?

After edit:

```
select t.user, vg_product_id,t.`platform`, pd.`mail`,
substring_index(group_concat(p.ts ORDER BY p.ts DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) as sub_start_ts, 
substring_index(group_concat(t.`expires_at`ORDER BY t.`expires_at` DESC SEPARATOR ','), ',', 1) as expired_time 
from users u
inner join tariff_subs_info t on (t.`user` = u.`user_xmpp_login` 
                                  and t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('^([A-Za-z]{2,3}(produsero|usero)+[0-9]{1,3})$')
                                  and t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('test')
                                  and t.vg_product_id REGEXP ("^(europe?|usa?|unlimited?|basic?)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)+(and?|ios?)+$" ))
left  join plus_data pd on (u.`user_xmpp_login` = pd.`user`)
inner join purchase_log p on (p.purchase_id = t.purchase_id)
WHERE (pd.mail not like '%guerrillamail.com' 
      and pd.mail NOT LIKE '%test%'
       or pd.mail is null) 
group by 1,2 ORDER BY DATE(p.ts);
```

I still have the following result , and 'test' in my user.

```
noadstestuser   basixxxf_ios    ios NULL    2015-10-26 14:00:32 2015-10-26 14:05:24
prodpurchasetest    basic_uscaxxs   ios NULL    2015-11-03 09:20:51 2015-11-03 09:25:41
esusertest  basic_uscxxxs   ios esusertest@ixn.ib   2015-11-04 13:53:48 2015-11-04 13:58:44
esusertest2 basic_uxxxx ios esusertedt2@iu.ycx  2015-11-04 14:11:12 2015-11-04 14:13:44
```

Comment: It is most probably because of `(\w+|\d+)?`. MySQL REGEXP does not support such constructs. Is that a word boundary check? Use `[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]`. Try also what Arth is saying in the answer below.

Comment: This place `([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\_)+` is also very problematic. I suggest replacing with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`. Or `[[:alnum:]_]+`.

Comment: I have changed to ' ("^(europe?|usa?|unlimited?|basic?)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+.)+(and?|ios?)+$" )' but I still have `esusertest,esusertest2 ` as result. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: No idea why you need the `.`, but since you do not want words *containing* `test`, you can remove the word boundaries: `and t.\`user\` NOT REGEXP ('test')` (or even `and t.\`user\` NOT LIKE ('%test%')`).

Comment: Do u mean this is not `[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]` and better I user `NOT REGEXP ('test')`instead? @Wiktor Stribiżew . I have written your last expression and It does answer, do you know why previously `[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]` doesn't work?  and if `NOT REGEXP ('test')` can be used for email such as testttt@testttt.com or not? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: The `(\w+|\d+)?` in your original expression is an invalid pattern in MySQL, I supposed you wanted to match a `test` as a whole word. I see I was wrong assuming that. Shall I post my suggestion as an answer?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew yes of course, test can come either in names or in emails like testttt@testttt.com. If you can provide me in your answer both condition I will be appreciated. Also, about the proper place I 've written my condition, I don't know if it is better to have it in the same place or I move the regular expression after where?

Comment: What's wrong with `LIKE '%test%'`?

Comment: @Arth: I also suggested that in one of the comments. Please feel free to update your answer with the corrected regexps.

Comment: I've updated my query, with 'Wiktor Stribiżew', I am not getting the `test` as name and also as email. ;) however, I have the problem of performance which @Arth suggested me to solve it with programming as I understood.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, I see that now.. my apologies. I'm now a bit confused as to what the correct regexps are.. I'll make my answer more generic instead :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much for your help. It would be a good idea if u add your answer as response;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL REGEXP does not support `\w` and `\d` shorthand character classes. So, `(\w+|\d+)?` subpattern is invalid in MySQL. Since the `?` quantifier makes the subpatterns optional (repeat one or zero times), you can remove them altogether.

Thus, `or '(\w+|\d+)?test(\w+|\d+)?'` will turn into `` and t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('test') ``, but it is equal in meaning to `` and t.`user` NOT LIKE '%test%' ``.

Next, `([a-zA-Z0-9]+|\_)+` is also very problematic since there are nested quantifiers (a `+` inside an alternation group that has another `+` quantifier applied). This is a classical scenario when catastrophical backtracking may occur. I suggest replacing this subpattern with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+` to match letters, digits or an underscore. Or its equivalent `[[:alnum:]_]+`.

Comment: what do u mean by `alnum`

Comment: `[:alnum:]` is a POSIX character class that matches letters and digits. See the [`REGEXP` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html).

Answer (score 1):

OK first off:

```
t.`user` NOT REGEXP (
  'usero pattern' or
  'test pattern'
)
```

is incorrect.. you can't `or` together two string inputs.. you need:

```
    t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('usero pattern')
AND t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('test pattern')
```

You should probably test all the expressions directly on the relevant tables first to make sure the logic is there.. as mentioned by @WiktorStribizew the word and digit character sets may not be recognized.

Next I'm guessing you don't need DISTINCT and GROUP BY in your query, you can probably just drop the DISTINCT.

Unfortunately, your regular expressions are going to hit every row.. there's not a lot you can do about that.

If it's a one off query, you'd probably just have to eat the time. You should probably run an EXPLAIN to check nothing crazy is happening to be sure though.

If you are running the queries regularly I suggest you split out the pertinent information via your application as you save the rows and then index the resultant extra columns, it won't be normalised.. but it's probably a situation where the performance boost will make it worth it.

**UPDATE**

For example your first two rows could be saved as:

```
[user:'noadstestuser', is_usero:0, is_test:1],
[user:'brusero2',      is_usero:1, is_test:0]
```

Then your

```
    t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('usero pattern')
AND t.`user` NOT REGEXP ('test pattern')
```

becomes simply

```
    t.is_usero = 0 AND t.is_test = 0
```

Much faster.. and you can index these fields if it helps.

Of course you'll have to do the matching before you save each row and this may be easier using your application logic (e.g. PHP code).

Comment: thanks 4 your info, Can u plz tell me where is the nest place to write this regular expression, at the end of my query? or is the same place as it is? I've updated the question. @Arth

Comment: regarding to your solution for splitting the rows , Is there any example that can you show me? I am new to the mysql and I am trying to improve.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi see update.. It doesn't really where you put the regexp conditions, but you should be consistent. Either put them all in the WHERE or  put each table's conditions in the JOIN conditions for that table. I simply meant, run your regexp patterns separately against each particular string separately first to debug! Trying to debug all the regular expressions in such a complex query could be frustrating :)

Comment: sorrt , I haven't get `[user:'noadstestuser', is_usero:0, is_test:1] ... ` Are u explaining sql or php? I've got confused . This query will be run once a week.

Comment: @MaryamPashmi That's just psuedo code.. I'm suggesting adding the columns `is_test` and `is_usero` to the table and saving the correct value on saving the rows.. you'll have to be careful with UPDATEs too, but I'm hoping this is a logging table. If you are using MariaDB (a mysql fork) you may be able to add these columns as PERSISTANT VIRTUAL column.